# XmlGregorianCalendar -> GregorianCalendar -> PostgreSQL Date issue

Tags: java, date, timezone

I need to store XmlGregorianCalendar in PostgreSQL date field.

In xml: `<Customer BirthDate="1973-05-10Z" Gender="Female">`

CustomerDTO:

```
@Column(name = "birthdate")
private Date birthDate;
```

Getting date from XML:

```
CustomerType c = ... //getting from XML
CustomerDTO dto = new CustomerDTO();
dto.setBirthDate(c.getBirthDate().toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
```

Sometimes in "birthdate" column I get BirthDate - 1 day (1973-05-09 instead of 1973-05-10). I think this is related to Timezone conversions. So, what I'm doing wrong and how to avoid it?
Thaks for your help.